# Xamarin.android, opening the image selector intent from dialog fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, dialog, fragment

I have a dialog fragment in my xamarin android app, where the user can fill in a form. In this form there is a button to select an image, but the only way I can find, to select an image is using the intent with the "*image" option set. 
The problem is that when i click the button, the intent wont open until i close the dialog fragment, and that is not a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have tested my code and it works fine on my side, please check it. :)

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Xamarin.android, opening the image selector intent from dialog fragment

You could use [StartActivityForResult()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.StartActivityForResult/p/Android.Content.Intent/System.Int32/) in your `DialogFragment` to impelment this feature.

To take picture from camera:

```
Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
StartActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//zero can be replaced with any action code
```

To pick photo from gallery:

```
Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri);
StartActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);
```

In your `Activity`, override the `OnActivityResult()`:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                Android.Net.Uri selectedImage = data.Data;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                Android.Net.Uri selectedImage = data.Data;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

## Update:

My `DialogFragment`:

```
public class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment//Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment
{
    public static MyDialogFragment NewInstance(Bundle bundle)
    {
        MyDialogFragment fragment = new MyDialogFragment();
        fragment.Arguments = bundle;
        return fragment;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
        Button button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dismiss_dialog_button);
        button.Click += delegate {
            Dismiss();
            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Dialog fragment dismissed!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        };

        Button dialog_button = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.dialog_button);
        dialog_button.Click += delegate {

            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            StartActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);//zero can be replaced with any action code

            //Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri);
            //StartActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1);
        };

        return view;
    }
}
```

My `Activity`:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    ...

    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        var ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        //Remove fragment else it will crash as it is already added to backstack
        Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment prev = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (prev != null)
        {
            ft.Remove(prev);
        }
        ft.AddToBackStack(null);
        // Create and show the dialog.
        MyDialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.NewInstance(null);
        //Add fragment
        newFragment.Show(ft, "dialog");
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: @RasmusSpaceflunkJørgensen, what type is your `DialogFragment`  and `Activity`?

Comment: @RasmusSpaceflunkJørgensen, `Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment` or `Android.App.DialogFragment`?